# How to subtract between timezone difference using moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need help I want to subtract the timezone difference of sydney australia and perth australia using moment js.

Here's the code

```
        var syd = moment.tz("Australia/Perth").format("Z");
        var syd2 = moment.tz("Australia/Sydney").format("Z");
```

Comment: Convert both dates to base timezone and perform operation. Also specify timezone of output